# C# Can't get String to DateTime conversion to work

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I've done some simple string -> DateTime conversions before using DateTime.ParseExact(), but I have a string that I can't seem to get parsed properly. I'm probably doing something very obvious wrong but I just can't see what it is.

The code is as follows:

```
string date = "Tue Jun 23, 2009 2:23 pm";
DateTime lastupdate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd MMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt", null);
```

Running it gives a FormatException. Is my formatting string incorrect?

ps
I've tried to use p.m. rather than pm in the input string but that didn't help either.

Comment: Jerry, I can't see either since you didn't post the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime lastupdate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd MMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"));
```

An error would occur if the culture was for example "fr-fr" or "de-de".

Comment: Why is this marked as correct? Your date is incorrect, which is causing the error.

Comment: That did it. I think my system's regional settings are set to Netherlands, so it's probably using that culture as well then. I had (still have) no idea what the supplied culture would do in the parsing process, as I literally supply the formatting of the string. My mistake. I'll do a bit of further reading into these functions :-)

Comment: Didn't edit the date. There's nothing wrong with it. June 23rd was a tuesday. I did edit the post to add the exception in there though. But weiqure's solution is valid, is it not?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to parse it exactly, or can you not just use DateTime.Parse?