# Function to convert string (yyyyMMddhhmm) into DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime

In my database I have a field date of type **varchar** where the date is stored in the following format **yyyyMMddhhmm**, with no spaces or other characters separating them.

Now I need to compare this date with a C# **DateTime**, therefore I need to convert the string into **DateTime**. The most logical way that I can think of is to extract from the variable `date` the sub-string related to year, month and day and create a new **DateTime** object:

```
var year = Convert.ToInt32(date.Substring(0, 4));

var month = Convert.ToInt32(date.Substring(4, 2));

var day = Convert.ToInt32(date.Substring(6, 2));

DateTime dateToCompare = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

Is there any available C# method that allows me to perform this conversion without writing all this code?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091359/c-sharp-cant-get-string-to-datetime-conversion-to-work you are not even close to being correct.  I have to downvote this question because you clearly DID NOT research the problem before you asked this qustion.

Comment: @Ramhound, I do not understand why you downvoted my question. In the question you showed me the format is 'ddd MMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt', which is clearly different than the format I deal with. And what do you mean with "you are not even close to being correct"?

Comment: @CiccioMiami: Just because it's got a different format doesn't mean the answer isn't fundamentally similar. Knowing that a method called `DateTime.ParseExact` exists and takes a format pattern should be enough to get you moving in the right direction (away from explicitly parsing substrings).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Absolutely - use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx):

```
DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "yyyyMMddHHmm",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note the `HH` for 24-hour instead of `hh` for 12-hour format.

Alternatively, you could use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx), which returns a true/false value to indicate whether or not the parsing was successful. If you're fully expecting all the data to be valid, and it's reasonable for an exception to be thrown otherwise, then `DateTime.ParseExact` is fine.

As a very different alternative, you could use [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com):

```
// Do this once...
var pattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantInfo("yyyyMMddHHmm");

// Do this repeatedly...
var parseResult = pattern.Parse(text);
if (parseResult.Success)
{
    LocalDateTime value = parseResult.Value;
    // Use the value...
}
else
{
    // Error... 
}
```

Or for the "just throw an exception" behaviour, just use `parseResult.Value` unconditionally.

EDIT: As an aside, is there any reason *why* you're storing dates in a varchar column? Can you fix your schema instead?

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the function I was looking for. In your answer you specify InvariantCulture. What happens if I specify another culture?

Comment: @CiccioMiami: Then it will parse it with that other culture. That's probably not going to be an issue if it's all numbers, but if you had a pattern using (say) the month name then you'd want to make sure you used the appropriate culture.

Comment: @FelicePollano: I'm somewhat biased, being the main author of Noda Time :)

Comment: I'm a little surprised nobody has mentioned just using string comparisons, since its already being stored in a comparable version. Just do a `ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm")` and the comparison will work

Comment: Personally, I feel uncomfortable using string comparisons to compare data that is meant to represent anything other than text.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method.

Answer (score 2):

according to what I found on forums, the following should work (I did not test it myself...)

```
string dateString = "20060425185231";

DateTime myDate;

myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,"yyyyMMddHHmmss", new DateTimeFormatInfo());

MessageBox.Show(myDate.ToString());
```

source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/c337c192-8047-4edf-83e2-c3511591c42f/

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
string dateString;
string format;
DateTime result;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

dateString = "201202130955";
format = "yyyyMMddhhmm"

result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```