# Sorting Date&Time string

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have these below strings to sort   (String Format: 121030-1833 --> YYDDMM-HHMM)

String Example:

```
121030-1833
120823-2034
120807-2014
120627-2316
120525-1136
111226-1844
```

I want to sort them from latest to old format.

Which sort method will be the best to use here?

### Updated problem statement

dictionary[String,string] "dictLocation" values with me, Want to sort the Dictionary according to its key (Key-YYMMDD-HHMM, latest to oldest)

```
{[110901-1226, sandyslocation.110901-1226]}
{[120823-2034, andyslocatio.120823-2034]}
{[110915-1720, mylocation.110915-1720]}
{[121030-1833, mylocation.121030-1833]}
```

I am trying this  var latestToOldest = dictLocation.OrderBy(key => key.Key)

It not giving me proper result, Is there anything i am missing ?

Comment: Do you only have the strings or do you have `DateTime` objects as well? Because if you have the latter you can sort those and then do the string conversion to your required format on the sorted data.

Answer (score 4):

As it happens, just sorting them in a descending way will work:

```
var latestToOldest = original.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

That's assuming you want to assume all values are within the same century. (If you can possibly change the format, I'd suggest using a 4-digit year for clarity.)

However, I would recommend parsing the values into `DateTime` values *as early as possible*. Whenever you can, keep your data in its most "natural" form. Fundamentally these are dates and times, not strings - so convert them into that format early, and keep them in that format as long as you possibly can.

Comment: I was just about to reference you answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9261695/626442...

Answer (score 1):

```
var sortedDateStrings = dateStrings.Sort().Reverse();
// or
var sortedDateStrings = dateStrings.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```